# OpenGL ES ReadPixels to bitmap From Texture larger than screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

So, I am implementing a screen to apply Effects (grain, negative, etc) to an image a user has taken from their camera or an image taken from their gallery. I am able to take the image that they have selected or taken and display it to them through the use of OpenGL at full resolution ( or scaled down maintaining aspect ratio depending on the max texture size of their device and the size of the image). Also, selecting the effect and applying to the texture works completely fine. As does taking the image and making a bunch of little preview thumbnails with that particular effect applied to it at 60x60 size. The way I do this is by using a FrameBuffer to render the image and saving it immediately to a Bitmap using glReadPixels.

The problem I am having is this: 
  I want to save the image with the selected filter applied to it as at the same dimensions as what is being display. So I use the same algorithm I use with saving the thumbnails but with the full image size instead of just 60x60. But when i do this, the bitmap that is saved is just the lower left corner of the image, and the rest is just a black screen. However, when I change the dimensions from say 3072x4096 to 1080x1920, the bitmap is drawn and saved correctly. I believe that this has to do with the dimensions of the device screen preventing glReadPixels from reading the full size since it is bigger then the device screen.

Does any have any insight into how to resolve this exactly? Or can explain to me why it is that the program behaves in this way.

Thank you for your help.

```
int[] mTextures = new int[2];
//... I set the Effect I want, this all works fine so I've ommited it for clarity...///
GLES20.glBindFrameBuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) // Bind Default Frame buffer
/// setup up program and everything works
GLES20.glViewPort(0,0,mTexWdith, mTexHeight) // should be something along 3160x4096, which is mImageHeight and mImageWdith
// COntinue with normal rendering///
GLES20.ActiveTextture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[1];
```

After this step is where I use the glesReadPixels
This method looks like this:

```
GLES20.glBindFrameBuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) // is this the correct binding?

//allocate byte buffer here. Works fine
GLES20.glReadPixels(0,0,mImageWidth, mImageHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES.INSIGNED, byteBuffer)
 GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLToolBox.checkGlError("store Pixels");
    pixelBuffer.rewind();

//set bitmap and use matrix to account for the image being vertically flipped
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(pixelBuffer);

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setScale(-1, 1);
    m.preRotate(180);

    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm,0,0,mImageWidth, mImageHeight, m, false);
```

Then I continue to save the image here into a file///

Comment: If you want to render and retrieve at a resolution higher than your window or screen provides, you will have to render to an offscreen surface, like an FBO.

Comment: Yes, I am using an FBO for rending the thumbnail versions of my image at 60x60 in size. However, when I attempt to do render the image near the Max texture size weird things start to happen. Like only the lower left corner of the image being drawn and the rest will appear black. Very strarnge considering the image at 60x60 work perfectly.

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on. You might reach some hw limits like maximum viewport size. But it can also be just a bug in your code. Without any further details, I can't really help.

Comment: I added some sudo code into the original post. I ommited things that I know are working correctly. But I wanted to demonstrate how I am binding the framebuffers and textures because that is the part that I am unsure of. Like it said, it works fine for generating images at 60x60 but not for the larger images

Comment: You explicitely use FB 0, which is the default framebuffer provided by the window (or whatever drawable your context is attached to). You are _not_ using any FBOs in this code, and you won;t be able to render images lareger than the screen that way.

Comment: Awesome, I feel like I should have known that but your explanation has made everything click for me finally. (This is my first go around with OpenGL). So what I should do is user GLES20.glGenFrameBuffer(1, mFBO) and then use GLES20.glBindFrameBuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFBO[0]) to bind it. That way the readPixels call will read from my Frame buffer, not the default frame buffer that the window generates? Thank you so Much!

Comment: well, more or less. just generating and binding it will not be enough. You will also need at least one color attachment. Maybe [this OpenGL wiki article](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) can help you with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derhass was correct that I was using the default FBO to render to a texture instead of creating my own Frame Buffer Object. When using the default FBO I could never read more pixels than what the device screen could display.(which resulted in just the pixels starting from coords (0,0) to (mScreenWidth,mScreenHeight) being displayed while the rest of the image's size was just black).

By generating your own FBO and settings its viewport to the desired width and height you can read pixels from the bound frame Buffer with glReadPixels as large as the devices maximum texture size.

Comment: Please, can you provide a sample?
Thank you